# ASN1 to proper example text

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, asn.1

I wanted to get the value sample for the ASN1 document that was giving,
Is there any available tools to get this?

```
RolesOfPSP ::= SEQUENCE
RoleOfPSP ::= SEQUENCE{
    roleOfPspOid
    roleOfPspName
RoleOfPspOid ::= OBJECT
OF RoleOfPSP
RoleOfPspOid,
RoleOfPspName }
IDENTIFIER
-- Object Identifier arc for roles of payment service providers
-- defined in the present document
etsi-psd2-roles OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::=
{ itu-t(0) identified-organization(4) etsi(0) psd2(19495) id-roles(1) }
-- Account Servicing Payment Service Provider (PSP_AS) role id-psd2-role-psp-as OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::=
{ itu-t(0) identified-organization(4) etsi(0) psd2(19495) id-roles(1) 1 }
-- Payment Initiation Service Provider (PSP_PI) role
id-psd2-role-psp-pi OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::=
{ itu-t(0) identified-organization(4) etsi(0) psd2(19495) id-roles(1) 2 }
-- Account Information Service Provider (PSP_AI) role id-psd2-role-psp-ai OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::=
{ itu-t(0) identified-organization(4) etsi(0) psd2(19495) id-roles(1) 3 }
-- Payment Service Provider issuing card-based payment instruments (PSP_IC) role id-psd2-role-psp-ic OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::=
{ itu-t(0) identified-organization(4) etsi(0) psd2(19495) id-roles(1) 4 }
-- Payment Service Provider role name corresponding with OID (i.e. PSP_AS, -- PSP_PI, PSP_AI, PSP_IC)
RoleOfPspName ::= utf8String (SIZE(256)) END
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ASN.1 sample here does not look complete.  It seems to have some overlapping definitions.  You can try it at http://asn1-playground.oss.com/ which is an online ASN.1 Compiler and encoder/decoder.  You can also find a list of ASN.1 Tools on the ITU-T ASN.1 Project page at https://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/Tools.aspx, which lists both Commercial and open-source ASN.1 Tools.